# Dockerized django taking long time for build the docker-compose

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework

I'm running a dockerized Django application: only Django + Postgres on local. When I start the application and go to any localhost URL, it takes up to 20-30 minutes to build.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3-alpine
LABEL maintainer="joyalcs2@gmail.com"
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY ./requirements.dev.txt /tmp/requirements.dev.txt
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

ARG DEV=false
RUN python -m venv /py && \
    apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client && \
    apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
        build-base postgresql-dev musl-dev && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    if [ $DEV = "true" ]; \
       then /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.dev.txt; \
    fi && \
    rm -rf /tmp && \
    adduser \
        --disabled-password \
        --no-create-home \
        django-user

ENV PATH="/py/bin:$PATH"
USER django-user
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.11"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - DEV=true
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    image: app:django
    container_name: rest_container
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

requirements.txt:

```
Django == 4.2.4
djangorestframework == 3.14.0
psycopg2 == 2.9.7
drf_spectacular == 0.26.4
```

I tried many times and i changed the image many time .but it takes so much time.Also, i used

Comment: Do you mean it takes 20-30 minutes to build the image, or 20-30 minutes to handle the first request?  The `volumes:` mount you show hides all of the source code in the image and can lead to some subtle problems, and it's known to have performance issues on some platforms, though usually not at this scale and less so for Python than other languages.

Comment: Re-arrange your Dockerfile lines to do the heavy but static jobs first and add the app data as late a possible. This way you can make more use of the layer caching.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the docker in a wrong way. Here's my reasons:

1. You should create seperate Dockerfiles for development and another.
2. You are building virtual environment while you use docker to isolate your apps so you don't need virtual environments.

I think with these you can improve your building performance. Hope it helps!